# Java display the actual Java code line for a line in StackTrace

Tags: java, line, stack-trace

Assume I am getting the following java Exception

```
ERROR - Error occured while reading properties. (MyPropertyReader.java) 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.x.MyPropertyReader.init(PropertyReader.java:**222**)
        at com.x.MyPropertyReader.<init>(PropertyReader.java:119)
```

How do you find out , what excatly the code block looks like at line 222 ?

For example: The above exception is due to the following line of code and I want to see the much like below line in log files.

```
propertyConfiguration.getProperty("REPORT_INFLUENCE_THRESHOLD"))).trim());
```

I want to see `REPORT_INFLUENCE_THRESHOLD` string in the log files. 
However I am curious in general what how to **programmatically** print line in 222 during execution.

Comment: I don't think this is directly possible, as in run-time,  your class files are in byte-code, so I guess your line 222 doesn't really exist anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need, obviously, **to have the source files in your classpath.** This or at least at a location you know you can find them.

Then you would use [`Throwable`'s `.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace--) which returns an array of [`StackTraceElement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html).

The latter has the source file name and line (IF AVAILABLE; a jar may, or may not, have been compiled with debug information); from then on, read, find line, print!

Comment: JAR alone is not enough I understand, I need to package the source files into the JAR as well. Looks like very difficult. Any other advice ? Even I cant have the whole line, having the used parameter :"REPORT_INFLUENCE_THRESHOLD" in this example would be nice.

Comment: while this solution is too cumbersome i understand java does not class footprint in memory and there is no other possible way to obtain lines automatically.